# WRF: minimal list of variables required by coupling a land surface model to the whole system

Tags: numerical-modelling, wrf, land-surface, land-surface-models

We are trying to couple our land surface model into WRF. As a first step, we'd like to know what is the minimal list of variables required by such coupling?

Comment: This depends on your land surface model. Create a list of all the inputs, and find their appropriate variables in WRF. Then create a list of all the outputs, and update the WRF variables that you want. The latter is completely up to you.

Comment: But what's the minimal requirement to make the coupling work? I see existing LSMs in WRF all have different input/output lists. Can I take the slab model, which has the minimal list of input/output variables, as the minimal case?

Comment: According to the README.namelist, you can run without any LSM by setting sf_surface_physics to 0, which implies no surface temperature evolution. So the absolute minimum is probably nothing. Slab sounds like a reasonable starting point to me.

Comment: @milancurcic thanks! so the slab model would be a sensible step to move on with.